# Reference View From Included Layout

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a fragment layout with the following include tag:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/ivRemoveData"
    layout="@layout/item_menu"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

item_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/not_passed_circle_level_item"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

I need to use method `ivIcon.setImageResource()`.

My fragment class:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_options.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_menu.view.*

class OptionsFragment : BaseFragment(), OptionsMVP.View
{
    override fun onCreateView(inflater : LayoutInflater, container : ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState : Bundle?) : View?
    {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_options, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view : View?, savedInstanceState : Bundle?)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ivRemoveData.ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete)
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
      at hobbajt.com.BubbleQuiz.Options.OptionsFragment.onViewCreated(OptionsFragment.kt:29)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
```

It seems that `ivIcon` is null, even though it's in the included layout. How can I reference this ImageView?

Comment: are you using kotlin extenstions?

Comment: Yes, I have in my module gradle:
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you give an id to `<include/>` tag it will override the id of parent included layout.

In your case `most probably`

```
android:id="@+id/ivRemoveData"
```

overrides the id of your `imageView`. And the id `ivIcon` could not be found.

You can change your xml like that:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    layout="@layout/item_menu"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: I was removed id from include tag, and then used ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete)

Comment: ^ That is what I was going to suggest. This answer does a good job of explaining the problem, but rather than renaming the include tag I would have just dropped the id and used the inherent ones from the included layout (which is what OP arrived on).

Comment: @Hobbajt that was the another solution. It will work too.

Comment: I also found another solution. I was removed id from item_menu and added cast: (ivRemoveData as ImageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete)

Comment: @AdamMc331 That won't work when you have the same item layout included several times. In this case, the trick is to wrap the item layout (Imageview) in a relative or linear layout